# mkdir -p fails when directory exists

Tags: linux, shell, mkdir

On one of our remote systems `mkdir -p $directory` fails when the directory exists. which means it shows

> mkdir: cannot create directory '$directory' : file exists

This is really puzzling, as I believed the contract of `-p` was that is always succeed when the directory already exists. And it works on the other systems I tried.

there is a user `test` on all of these systems, and `directory=/home/test/tmp`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

This could be caused if there is already a **file** by the same name located in the directory.

Note that a directory cannot contain both a file and folder by the same name on linux machines.

Comment: that's exactly what is was and I am currently reviewing and fixing our scripts

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was failing because there was a sym link with the same name.

Answer (score 4):

Check to see if there is a file (not a directory) with a name same as $directory.

Answer (score 4):

mkdir -p won't create directory if there is a file with the same name is existing in the same directory. Otherwise it will work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Was your directory a [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)-based network mount by any chance?

In addition to a **file with that name already existing** (other answer), this can happen when a **FUSE process that once mounted something at this directory crashed** (or was killed, e.g. with `kill -9` or via the Linux OOM killer).

Check in `mount` if the FUSE mount is still listed there. If yes, you should be able to unmount it and fix the situation using `fusermount -uz`.

To see what is happening in detail, run `strace -fy mkdir -p $directory`, which shows all syscalls involved and their return values.

---

I consider the error messages emitted in this case a bug in `mkdir -p` (in particular the `gnulib` library):

When you run it on a dir that had a FUSE process mounted but that process crashed, it says

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mymount’: File exists
```

which is rather highly inaccurate, because [the underlying `stat()`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/mkdir-p.c?id=a02a6f2e1dcad63999954bb72825a084800742ae#n152) call returns `ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)`; but `mkdir` propagates up the less-specific error from [the previous `mkdir()` sycall](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/mkdir-p.c?id=a02a6f2e1dcad63999954bb72825a084800742ae#n130).
It's extra confusing because the man page says:

```
   -p, --parents
          no error if existing, make parent directories as needed
```

so it shouldn't error if the dir exists, yet `ls -l /` shows:

```
d????????? ? ?    ?       ?            ? files
```

so according to this (`d`), it *is* a directory, but it isn't according to `test -d`.

---

I believe a better error message (which `mkdir -p` should emit in this case) would be:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/mymount’: Transport endpoint is not connected
```

Comment: if this is the case, what's the fix?

Comment: @adrian To fix: Check in `mount` if the FUSE mount is still listed there. If yes, you should be able to unmount it and fix the situation using `fusermount -uz`. I've added that to the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: file named -p already exists.

Explanation:
You may wonder how a file -p is created when you only created a directory.It's because everything in Unix is a file,even directories you create is a file.

Solution:
Method 1: rename existing directory ('-p' in your case)

```
sudo mv -p -p/renaming
```

we have moved -p into a new directory -p/renaming or say renamed it.
Now, rerun the command

```
mkdir -p
```

There should be no errors this time.

Another problem you may encounter: Permission Denied
This occurs when you do not have the write permission
you can check by using

```
ls -lad -p
```

you will see something like this
[the 'd' indicates this is a directory and r-x indicates the user has only permission to read/execute but no permission to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrpFJ.png)
so to give permission to the user, use:

```
chmod u+w -p
```

Now try again

```
ls -lad -p
```

and you will see
[The user has now permission to write](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wku8.png)

Now, you can create the directory

```
mkdir -p
```